# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))

Tags: python, flask

The following error occurred when I ran a Python program from the command line:

```
File "manager/start_server.py", line 6, in <module>
    from manager.responses import start_response
  File "/home/rj/dlruijie/slave-server/manager/responses.py", line 20, in <module>
    CONTAINER_OBJ = Containers()
  File "/home/rj/dlruijie/slave-server/manager/node.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.client.version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 171, in version
    return self.api.version(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 159, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 183, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

It happens a lot.But the first time I put the program on the server, I didn't have this error.

Comment: This is Docker related issue - it seems the docker library tries to connect docker, but the socket does not exist - make sure your docker deamon is running: `sudo systemctl start docker`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you might be running the container that might be connecting another service(DB access or other container service) that was only accessible from that environment but is not accessible from your local environment.